How to Run Liquibase Updates Programmatically in Version 4.29 with Rollback Support?
I'm currently using Liquibase version 4.29 in my Spring application and I want to run Liquibase updates programmatically instead of via the command line. I have enabled Liquibase with the property liquibase.enabled=true, and while the migration scripts run successfully when I start my application, I am encountering issues with rollbacks.
When I run migrations using the Liquibase command line interface (CLI) and then perform a rollback using liquibase rollback , it works as expected. However, when I see that Liquibase runs the scripts when I start the Spring application, the rollback does not work as expected; it returns "0 changes rolled back."
I've noticed that the liquibase.update() method has been deprecated. The documentation suggests using the following approach:
java.sql.Connection connection = openConnection(); // Your openConnection logic here
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("path/to/changelog.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());

Given that update() is deprecated, what is the recommended way to execute Liquibase updates programmatically while ensuring that:
Liquibase migrates the scripts successfully, or else the Spring application fails to start if the migration fails.
Rollbacks work correctly, similar to the CLI.
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

are you using tags for liquibase?

@JuliyanageSilva yes, i am using tags

Try this with this dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.23.0</version> 
</dependency>

And then this:
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

public void rollbackToTag(String tag) throws Exception {
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance()
                .findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(
                        new JdbcConnection(connection));
        Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml",
                new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(),
                database);
        liquibase.rollback(tag, "");
    }
}


@Maddy did this work for you?
